# How to match a particular letters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a string (for example: "Hello"). I'd like to test that string against a set of characters in javascript (for example "j" "h" "p" "q" and "y").

This is what I tried so far:

```
var re = new RegExp("/[jgpqy]/i");
console.log(re.test("Hello"));
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should take some time to clarify it...

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(re.test(Hello));
```

should be `console.log(re.test("Hello"));`

For the regex part, just learn it:

https://regexone.com/

Comment: How to check for only particular alphabets alone